# Can somebody help convert URLSession from Swift to Kotlin

Tags: swift, urlsession, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I want to make Multiplatform Weather App with Kotlin. And I also want get weather data separate for Android and iOS in common module.

With Android I haven't any problem, but with iOS part I have. I want to use Foundation framework to get and serialise data with URLSession. But it doesn't work.

Here is my Weather Model.

```
    package com.example.weatherappversion3.shared

    data class WeatherData (
        val cod: String,
        val message: Long,
        val cnt: Long,
        val list: List<ListElement>,
        val city: City
    )
    
    data class City (
        val id: Long,
        val name: String,
        val coord: Coord,
        val country: String,
        val population: Long,
        val timezone: Long,
        val sunrise: Long,
        val sunset: Long
    )
    
    data class Coord (
        val lat: Double,
        val lon: Double
    )
    
    data class ListElement (
        val dt: Long,
        val main: MainClass,
        val weather: List<Weather>,
        val clouds: Clouds,
        val wind: Wind,
        val visibility: Long,
        val pop: Double,
        val sys: Sys,
        val dtTxt: String,
        val snow: Rain? = null,
        val rain: Rain? = null
    )
    
    data class Clouds (
        val all: Long
    )
    
    data class MainClass (
        val temp: Double,
        val feelsLike: Double,
        val temp_min: Double,
        val temp_max: Double,
        val pressure: Long,
        val seaLevel: Long,
        val grndLevel: Long,
        val humidity: Long,
        val tempKf: Double
    )
    
    data class Rain (
        val the3H: Double
    )
    
    data class Sys (
        val pod: Pod
    )
    
    enum class Pod {
        D,
        N
    }
    
    data class Weather (
        val id: Long,
        val main: MainEnum,
        val description: String,
        val icon: String
    )
    
    enum class MainEnum {
        Clear,
        Clouds,
        Rain,
        Snow
    }
    
    data class Wind (
        val speed: Double,
        val deg: Long,
        val gust: Double
    )
```

And here is my request:

```
    package com.example.weatherappversion3.shared

    import com.example.weatherappversion3.shared.constants.Constants
    //import cocoapods.Alamofire.*
    import platform.Foundation.*
    import platform.darwin.NSObject
    
    //import SwiftyJSON
    
    actual class WeatherManager {

    actual var weatherData: WeatherData? = null
    var data = NSData()
    //https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=e83bce43f40758140ef6927fda5cfc85&units=metric&lat=48.51320000&lon=32.25970000
    var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${Constants().AppId}&units=${Constants().units}&lat=${Constants().lat}&lon=${Constants().lon}"
    actual fun getWeatherForecastFor(updateUI: ()->Unit) {
        println("Start request for iOS")
        asyncRequest(url)
        updateUI()
    }

    fun asyncRequest(url: String) {

        val delegate = object : NSObject(), NSURLSessionDataDelegateProtocol {

            override fun URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData: NSData) {
                data = didReceiveData
            }

            override fun URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError: NSError?) {
                val response = task.response
                if (response == null || (response as NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode.toInt() != 200) {
                    return
                }

                if (didCompleteWithError != null) {
                    return
                }

            }
        }

        val session = NSURLSession.sessionWithConfiguration(
            NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
            delegate,
            delegateQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
        )

        session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string = url)).resume()
    }

    actual fun getWeatherForecastForSpecialCity(city: String) {

    }

}
```

Comment: What does not work, and how ? Does it build, what's the error?

Comment: Yes, it builds. And actually I get some data. But how to serialise NSData into my WeatherData?

Comment: The usual go-to solution for multiplatform serialization in Kotlin would be [Kotlinx serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization). I'm not familiar with the Foundation framework or URLSession, but it is quite likely you can work something out with this.

Comment: Is there a reason for you to work with different networking libs for Android and iOS? Why not share this API layer with multiplatform Kotlin clients like Ktor + Kotlinx serialization? This way you could write the code only once

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want to make it work separately and to learn how convert Swift code into Kotlin

Answer (score 2):

[Kotlinx serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) is currently the recommended way of doing multiplatform serialization, it supports `js`, `native` and `jvm` targets

[Here you can see](https://github.com/halcyonmobile/MultiplatformPlayground/blob/master/commonModel/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/halcyonmobile/multiplatformplayground/model/Application.kt) an example of kotlinx serialization

Answer (score 1):

In pure iOS, you would use the `Codable` protocol on your data, or manually decode using the `JSONDecoder` class from Foundation framework.

The Kotlin equivalent is Gson. There is probably other solutions.

**Edited :** Yes, there is other solution, see Kotlinx ( thanks to @joffrey for his comment ) - https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines

```
    data class WeatherData (
        @SerializedName("cod_key")  // Optional field name
        val cod: String,
        val message: Long,
        val cnt: Long,
        val list: List<ListElement>,
        val city: City
    )

    didReceiveData() {
        val weather = Gson().fromJson<WeatherData>(data, WeatherData::class.java)
    }
```

https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Gson is JVM-only, and uses reflection to modify private fields, which is usually not ideal (at least in Kotlin). Kotlinx serialization is more appropriate in general for Kotlin because it knows more about Kotlin features (sealed classes, default values, value classes etc), and it's multiplatform.

Comment: Thanks @Joffrey , I have added your comment in my answer.